# Find the first quadratic form of the surface $z=z(x, y)$

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

Find the first quadratic form of the surface $z=z(x, y)$

The surface can be seen as $(0, 0, z)$? If so, then I have that $E=p^2,\, F=pq$ and $G=q^2$, where $p=\partial_xz,\, q=\partial_yz$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Do not forget the coordinates $x$ and $y$, writing just $(0,0,z)$ you don't even get a surface! Consider $\varphi(x,y) = (x,y,z(x,y))$, and then compute $$E = \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}, \quad F = \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x},\quad \mbox{and}\quad G = \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y}.$$